# Seconds of moment object are changing on every render and have values that can't exist

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

I render a date with `moment` but for some reason, the seconds of some objects are changing after every rerender. The strange part is that I'm not sure how can the seconds be more than 60.

```
{moment(comment?.created_at).format('DD/MM/YYYY hh:ss')}
```

I also sort them, not sure if that's related:

```
{comment?.replies?.sort((a,b) => moment(a.created_at) - moment(b.created_at)).map(reply =>
```

[image]

EDIT:
So I render comments and replies which look something like this:

```
{
  "post_content": "Content of post",
  "comments": [
      {
      "comment_content": "First Comment",
      "comment_replies": [{ 
         "reply_content": "First reply"
               }]
      }]
}
```

I'm sorting the comments and replies and then rendering them:

```
   <List>
            {data?.comments?.sort((a,b) => moment(a.created_at) - moment(b.created_at)).map(comment => {
                return (<div> 
                    <Comment comment={comment} data={data} setData={setData}/> 
                        <div>
                        {comment?.replies?.sort((a,b) => moment(a.created_at) - moment(b.created_at)).map(reply => {
                            return (
                                <Box component="div" m={3}>
                                    <Reply commentId={comment.comment_id} data={data} setData={setData} reply={reply}/>
                                </Box>
                            )
                        })}
                        </div>
                    </div>);
            })}
        </List>
```

EDIT 2:
The comment object after the date is rendered.

```
{
"created_at": "2021-04-03T18:45:57.987068Z",
"comment_id": "7fabbade-23e0-47ab-9e46-af37d07a46b1",
"content": "Second Comment",
"user": "usernametest",
"replies": [
    {
        "reply_id": "b3f96c47-bd46-481b-b485-ea0b19977031",
        "content": "First Reply",
        "user": "usernametest"
    }
]
```

}

EDIT 3:
The showReply is a flag to show the reply input, and patch is a flag to show the update/edit button.

```
<Typography
                      component="span"
                      variant="body2"
                      className={classes.inline}
                      color="textPrimary"
                    >
                      {comment?.user} 
                    </Typography>
                    - {moment(comment?.created_at).format('DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm')}
                    {console.log(comment)}
                    <div>
                    {localStorage.getItem("vettageToken") && localStorage.getItem("vettageToken") !== "undefined" &&
                      localStorage.getItem("vettageToken") !== null ? 
                    <div>
                      <a onClick={e => setShowReply(!showReply)}>Reply</a>
                      {patch ? <a onClick={patchComment}>Update</a> : <a onClick={e => setPatch(!patch)}>Edit</a> }
                      <a onClick={e => deleteComment()}>Delete</a>
                      {showReply && 
                        <div>
                          <TextField
                            id="outlined-multiline-static"
                            label="Add a comment"
                            multiline
                            rows={4}
                            value={reply}
                            onChange={e => setReply(e.target.value)}
                            defaultValue="Default Value"
                            variant="outlined"
                          />
                          <Button onClick={e => postReply()}>Reply</Button>
                        </div>
                      }
                    </div>
```

Comment: Could you provide more code for eg what are you doing in render()

Comment: Please also add the `comment` object.

Comment: You're showing seconds *without minutes*, which is feasibly confusing things.

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/66482206/2873538

Comment: @YatinGaikwad I've added the render function, let me know if the comment and reply components are also needed.

@jonrsharpe I actually didn't notice that. I've changed it to `hh:mm:ss` and the seconds are now increasing by 1 for every render.

Comment: Could you please also render the `comment` object where you are rendering the date. I am sure, `comment.createdAt` ins undefined that's why its ia updating value at each render update

Comment: @AjeetShah It seems that I'm facing that problem. Is there a reason as to why?

Comment: Moments are mutable. Days.js has a very similar API but is immutable. Perhaps simply swapping for that would resolve your issue.

Comment: Also, can you safely sort `moment`s? I'm not sure?

Comment: @Slbox But why are they changing when they're fixed and coming from the API? EDIT: I did the sorting with `Date` but the same thing was happening.

Comment: Was using a and b variables in nested map problem? try changing those variable names since they are already used in the parent map function

Comment: @ShivamSingla Added the comment object after the date is rendered with `console.log`. When I go and type a reply, the `console.log` isn't called again. 

@YatinGaikwad Changed the but the problem still occurs.

Comment: When you change the comment value, you update created_date also?

Comment: @SoufianeBoutahlil No, the created_at date is only set when the comment is created and it's fixed value coming from the API.

Comment: what do you mean by one comment is created? when you click on the save button or something like this?

Comment: Yeah, when you click the Save button, the comment is created and the `created_at` timestamp is set. But when I go and edit the comment, the seconds are changing even though there's no way that the `created_at` stamp is changed.

Comment: Could you please add whole code for the comment component, stripping styles and other functionality.